# Script is very slow. Making sure only one checkbox is selected per row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, triggers

I have a google sheet workbook with four sheets that have surveys. Each survey has one question per row, with two to four choices that can be selected. Each choice has a corresponding checkbox. I need to make sure that if the user changes a selection in a row then the previously selected checkbox is unchecked. This works fine, but it's slow in unchecking the old choice. At it's very fastest it takes a couple of seconds but it can take 7 or 8 seconds sometimes. It seems to me it should take just a fraction of a second, there's not that much being done. Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

Here's my onEdit function and one of the functions it calls. All of the called functions are basically the same, with different numbers of rows, and they all behave about the same as far as slowness goes.

```
function onEdit(e) {
   
  // get event object data: sheet name, row number and column number
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  const col = e.range.columnStart;
  const currentsheet = sheet.getSheetName()
   
  switch(currentsheet) {
    case "Adaptive Behavior":
      onEditADaptive(sheet, row, col)
    case "Social Communication":
      onEditSocComm(sheet, row, col)
    case "Behavior 6-18":
      onEditBehavior618(sheet, row, col)
    case "BRIEF-2 Parent Report":
      onEditBRIEF2(sheet, row, col)

  }
}



function onEditBehavior618(mySheet, myRow, myCol) {
  
  switch(myCol) {
    
        // case when column C is checked   C-E-G
        case 3:
          mySheet.getRangeList(["E" + myRow,"G" + myRow]).uncheck();
          break;
    
        // case when column E is checked
        case 5:
          mySheet.getRangeList(["C" + myRow,"G" + myRow]).uncheck();
          break;
    
        // case when column G is checked
        case 7:
          mySheet.getRangeList(["C" + myRow,"E" + myRow]).uncheck();
          break;
        
        // cell is outside of columns C, E or G
        default:
          return;
    
      }
}
```

This is the technique I found through a search, and it works fine other than being slow.

Comment: My opinion onEdit is just slow, and you can't do much to optimize that... You should probably go with Web App https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Not sure if this is doable for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll do what I can do get my way to work first before trying to go that route, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this section of your code

```
var timer = null;
switch(currentsheet) {
  case "Adaptive Behavior":
    timer = new Timer("onEditADaptive")
    onEditADaptive(sheet, row, col);
    timer.stop();
    break;
  case "Social Communication":
    timer = new Timer("onEditSocComm")
    onEditSocComm(sheet, row, col);
    timer.stop();
    break;
  case "Behavior 6-18":
    timer = new Timer("onEditBehavior618")
    onEditBehavior618(sheet, row, col);
    timer.stop();
    break;
  case "BRIEF-2 Parent Report":
    timer = new Timer("onEditBRIEF2")
    onEditBRIEF2(sheet, row, col);
    timer.stop();
    break;
 }
```

Add Timer to your Code.gs

```
class Timer {
  constructor(label) {
    if( label === undefined ) label = "Timer";
    this.label = label;
    this.start = new Date();
  }
  stop() {
    let end = new Date();
    end = (end.valueOf()-this.start.valueOf())/1000;
    Logger.log(this.label+": elapsed time: "+end.toFixed(3)+" sec" );
  }
}
```

Hereis an example of viewing the execution log for onEdit

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    Logger.log("Hello from onEdit");
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err);
  }
}
```

I simply edit a cell and then from the script editor go to Executions on the left hand side

[image]

Comment: How would I change that to make it more efficient? Each sheet has to be handled differently since they each have a different number of checkboxes and/or they checkboxes are in different columns. What is it about the way I'm doing it that would slow it down, and what would make it faster?

Comment: In a `switch case` statement if you don't have a break after the case in question it will execute the next case.  For example if sheet is "Adaptive Behavior" it will execute `onEditADaptive` followed by `onEditSocComm` followed by `onEditBehavior618` followed by `onEditBRIEF2`

Comment: I guess I'm missing something - I do have a break after each one of them.

Comment: Oops - I didn't realize you'd added those in there, my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I added the Breaks after each case just as you showed, still just as slow.

Comment: Try adding the `Timer` as I have shown above.  And provide your execution log.

Comment: I'm new to sheets and scripts, I come from a desktop background using Access, Excel, etc. I can't tell exactly what this is doing, Is this just to see how long it's taking internally and showing that in the logger? I've never used the logger before so am not familiar with it.

Comment: Exactly, I've show a simple example of onEdit() and the execution log above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. Haven't been working the last few days so just getting around to this. I have a feeling all I'll find is that it's a 'flaw' in Sheets and Script and there's no way to speed this up noticeably, but hopefully I'm wrong. I could use use dropdowns rather than the checkboxes (Excel has radio buttons, which takes care of only allowing one selection, but Sheets doesn't), but it's 'less aesthetically pleasing'.